# Is it possible to access properties of a subclass if the object's reference variable is a superclass type?

Tags: c#

I am new to programming and to c# and I just wanna know if there is a way for me to initialize the subclass fields through property if my reference variable is a superclass type.

**Example**

```
Character test = new Archer();
test.Damage = 5; // Damage is from the Fighter Class
```

SuperClass **Character**

```
abstract class Character
{
//Superclass common
}
```

Class **Fighter** subclass of **Character**

```
abstract class Fighter : Character
{
    private int damage
    public int Damage {
        get
        {
            return damage;
        }
        set
        {
            damage = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Class **Archer** subclass of **Fighter**

```
class Archer : Fighter
{
//stuffs that only archers can do
}
```

Comment: If you try compiling this the compiler will tell you it's not possible

Comment: you could pass the value of Damage as a constructor parameter while initializing Archer, or assign the variable `test` to a `Fighter` variable like : `var fighter = test as Fighter; fighter.Damage = 5;`

Comment: Should I use the most specific class instead? like Archer test = new Archer();

Comment: The variable `test` is of type `Character`, which does not have a `Damage` property.

Comment: In this case you could use Fighter instead of concrete: `Fighter test = new Archer();`

Comment: `(test as Archer).Damage = 5;`

Answer (score 10):

> I am new to programming and to c#

Welcome aboard. Let me start by encouraging you to get a good book, take a course, get a tutor, or whatever you do to learn a subject. **StackOverflow is explicitly not a tutorial site**.

> is there is a way for me to initialize the subclass fields through property if my reference variable is a superclass type?

The beginner programmer answer is: no.

If you want to access a property of a more-derived type then the reference you have in hand has to be *known* to be of that more-derived type.

C# is what we call a "statically typed" language, meaning that there has to be "static" -- that is, known to the compiler -- type information that demonstrates that each expression is valid.

The advanced programmer answer is: yes, but do not do it.

C# has a "dynamic" mode; if you said

```
dynamic test = new Archer();
test.Damage = 123;
```

That would work. **Do not do this**.  Two reasons. First, *if you turn off static type checking, static type checking is turned off*.  You could write

```
dynamic test = new Archer();
test.Damaeg = 123;
```

and the compiler would allow it, and your program would crash at runtime.  **Static type checking is there to help you. Use it.**

Second, we added `dynamic` so that people could write C# programs that interact with dynamic languages such as Python and JavaScript.  Use it for that, when you need to, not as an end-run around static type checking.

> Should I use the most specific class instead?

You should use a *specific enough* class. In this case, `Fighter` or `Archer` would do.

While we are looking at your code, a few other comments:

```
private int damage
public int Damage {
    get
    {
        return damage;
    }
    set
    {
        damage = value;
    }
```

That is correct, but that is how you'd write it in C# 1.0. In any version of C# from 3.0 on, you would typically write the much shorter form:

```
public int Damage { get; set; }
```

and let the compiler manage the backing field for you.

Consider also: *do you want the `Damage` property to be settable outside of the class hierarchy? If the answer is "no" then make it a `protected set;` property. Do you want it to be settable outside of the `Fighter` class? If no, make it `private set;` Do you want it to be settable *at all* after it is initially set?  If no, then (in C# 7) omit the `set` entirely and it will be only settable in the constructor.

Also, this is probably too advanced for you right now, but it may also stop you from going down a bad path. I wrote a series of articles specifically about the problem space you are exploring, and common pitfalls that even advanced programmers fall into. It starts here: https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/  -- I talk more about abusing `dynamic` in that series as well.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question, you *can* set the value, you just have to cast before:

```
(test as Archer).Damage = 5; 
//Or
//(test as Fighter).Damage = 5;
```

Now, if you *should* do that, check Eric's answer and his blog.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of c#:

```cs
if (test is Archer archer)
   archer.Damage = 5;
```

This ensures program does not crash with "null exception", if "test" is the wrong type.